# How to use ajax in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am a very beginner to `mvc` and `ajax` both.

I have tried many examples on net but I don't understand how ajax is used practically?

I have a controller named `members` which has `GetAllMembers` Method.
`GetAllMembers` returns a `List<Members>`

Now I want to use JQuery and ajax something like :

```
 $(document).click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Members/GetAllMembers",
            success: function () {

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Failed to get the members");
            }
        });
    });
```

Is my URL right?

Upon success I want to display that List in a ListBox.
How can I get it? Can anyone give me a start?

Comment: surely a google search could give you a good example of how to do an ajax call with jQuery to your MVC app.  The URL needs to be "/Members/GetAllMembers". And do you really want this to happen on $(document).click?

Comment: sorry, I want it on $(document).load and I have a parameter to be passed in to GetAllMembers(). So, may I pass that parameter in URL?

Comment: can you post your controller method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Members/GetAllMembers", //Your required php page
                data: "id="+ data, //pass your required data here
                success: function(response){  //You obtain the response that you echo from your controller
                    $('#Listbox').html(response); //The response is being printed inside the Listbox div that should have in your html page.
                },
               error: function () {
                   alert("Failed to get the members");
               }
            });
```

Hope this will help you.. :)

Comment: I dont usnderstand `response` in your code. Where and how should I get the value of 'response'?

Comment: Suppose you want to print say Productname in your listbox,first you should be passing the product id to the controller function.The id could be obatined by using $_POST['id'].Then you might want to find the product name based on this id.Once you obtain this Product name just echo it from your controller which is similar to a return.This return value is the response that is get from the controller.

Comment: After your suggestions I tried the code as below : `$(document).click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Members/ListOfAllOppositeTypeUsersWithTheirRespectiveData",
            data: "LoggedInUserOppositeType = " + 2,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("S");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("F");
            }
        });
    });` But I always get F. What is the mistake?

Comment: It is right as per my knowledge and my code in controller is `public List<Member> ListOfAllOppositeTypeUsersWithTheirRespectiveData(int LoggedInUserOppositeType)
        {

            using (FileSharingDBEntities db = new FileSharingDBEntities())
            {
                List<Member> Members = db.Members.Where(p => p.MemberTypeID == LoggedInUserOppositeType).ToList();
                return Members;
            }
        }`

Comment: Sorry mate.I can't write the code for you.Check if your ajax url is correct using firebug xhr under the net tab.Thats all i can do to help you.No hard-feelings mate... :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining me some concepts of ajax

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Members/GetAllMembers",
                success: function (result) {
    // do your code here
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed to get the members");
                }
            });
        });
```

So your request give response in "result" variable. So you have to easily manage result variable value in `foreach` loop and set value in ListBox HTML.

Comment: I don't understand the `result`

Comment: result variable contains value of GetAllMembers function return value. You have to bind all members value in string variable and return this varible to ajax function. So its automatically result contains this value and after that you have to manage that value in foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example:

suppose you have this html:

```
<p>List Box - Single Select<br>
<select id="listBox" name="listbox">

</select>
</p>
```

So we have this js:

```
var template = '<option value="$value">$name</option>';

var getAllMembers = function() {
$.ajax({
 url: 'Members/GetAllMembers',
 dataType: 'json', //Assuming Members/GetAllMembers returns a json
 success: function(response) {
  $.each(response, function(index){
   var option = template.replace(/\$value/g, this.value)
                        .replace(/\$name/g, this.name);
   $('#listBox').append(option);
  });
 }
});
};
```

**EDIT:** Now you only need to call `getAllMembers();` function.

Hope this help.

Pablo.